# It is showing NULL when reading and writing excel in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class TestClass2 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
try{
FileInputStream fis= new FileInputStream(new File("E:\\Garvit\\GarvitDoc.xlsx"));
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
Sheet s= wb.getSheet("GarvitDoc");
System.out.println(s.getRow(1).getCell(0).getStringCellValue());
System.out.println(s.getRow(1).getCell(1).getStringCellValue());
System.out.println(s.getRow(1).getCell(2).getStringCellValue());
System.out.println(s.getRow(1).getCell(3).getStringCellValue());
System.out.println(s.getRow(1).getCell(4).getStringCellValue());
} catch(Exception e)
{
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}


}
```

}

When I run this code it is showing 'NULL'

Comment: This is good for you.

Comment: This has nothing to do with selenium, whatever it is. Selenium is not even imported.